# Noise removal on nighttime light data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am carrying out a nighttime light analysis on Nepal. I have searched https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/interest/gas_flares_countries_shapefiles.html to download gas flare shapefile for Nepal but couldn't find it.

I tried using the digital number analysis using the map algebra in the Spatial Analysis Toolbox in ArcGIS, using the formula
`(0.00001*average_cvgfile -0.9)`, but the image seems to be same without actually removing the background noise on the image.

How else can I carry out noise removal?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks... How about it now?

Comment: I suggest improving your question by adding more details. That way it is more likely to attract a potential answerer.